# Equation with five or more unknowns

Tags: probability, statistics

$$x + y + z + a + b = 1$$ and

$$ \frac{x}{y} = \frac{y}{z} = \frac{z}{a} = \frac{a}{b}$$

where $x > y > z > a > b$, and all of them are bigger than "0"

so what is $x$, $y$, $z$, $a$ and $b$?

Is there a formula for five, less or more unknowns?

Comment: Actually you have 6 equations and 6 unknowns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have five unknowns and *four* equations.

If you set
$$
\frac{x}{y}=\frac{y}{z}=\frac{z}{a}=\frac{a}{b}=k
$$
you have $x=ky$, $y=kz$, $z=ka$, $a=kb$, so also
$$
z=k^2b,\quad y=k^3b,\quad x=k^4b
$$
The equation so becomes
$$
(k^4+k^3+k^2+k+1)b=1
$$
You want solutions with $k>1$, so $x>y>z>a>b$ would be granted. You have obviously infinitely many solutions: for any $k>1$,
$$
b=\frac{1}{k^4+k^3+k^2+k+1}<a=kb<z=ka<y=kz<x=ky
$$

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Since $$\frac{x}{y} = \frac{y}{z} = \frac{z}{a} = \frac{a}{b}$$

We can conclude that $x,y,z,a,b$ are in G.P with $x$ as the first term and  $\frac yx$ as the common ratio.

Hence 
$$z = \frac{y^2}{x}$$
$$a = \frac{y^3}{x^2}$$
$$b = \frac{y^4}{x^3}$$

$$S_n = \frac{x\left(\left(\frac yx \right) ^5 -1\right)}{\left(\frac yx \right) -1}$$

$$S_n=1 \implies \frac{x\left(\left(\frac yx \right) ^5 -1\right)}{\left(\frac yx \right) -1} = 1$$

$$y^4 + y^3x + y^2x^2 + yx^3 + x^4 = x^3$$

Plugging the equations into Wolfram Alpha give us $4$ solutions.

$$x=0,y=0$$
$$x=1,y=-1$$
$$x=1,y=0$$
$$x\approx 1.48466,y\approx -0.899453$$

It is easy to check that $(x=1,y=-1)$ is the solution which makes the terms 
$x=1,y=-1,z=1,a=-1,b=1$

Another trivial case occurs when the common ratio is $1$ and the variables become equal.

Then , $x=y=z=a=b=\frac 15$

Comment: thanks but if x > y > z > a > b?

Comment: Four solutions?

Answer (score 1):

A trivial solution is $x=y=z=a=b=0.2$
Another is $x=z=b=1$ and $y=a=-1$
Maybe this will help you see other solutions

Comment: thanks but I forgot a big explanation, "x > y > z > a > b". sorry